# CSS relative positioning

Tags: css

I want the `.tag` element to be placed literally on top of the img tag.  I've tried `position: relative` but it's not quite working as I'd like it to.  I don't want the `.tag` to push the image below it.

```
<div class="first center">
    <div class='tag'></div>
    <img src=''/>
</div>
```

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words.

Comment: CSS doesn't, but it's still pretty useful, how about some of that too?

Comment: It sounds like you are simulating a background image - why not just use a background image?

Comment: @David Dorward: I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`position: relative` on the outer div, and `position: absolute` on the <strike>two elements</strike> `div` inside.

See here for an explantion of why this works:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XakBp/

Comment: Well, I was making a demo, but @Šime Vidas' looks good. +1 to him.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="first center" style="position: relative;">
    <img src='' />
    <div class='tag' style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

You can position the tag absolute within a relatively positioned parent container.

Note, do not inline your styles, obviously.